# php: trim <br> from the end of a string?

Tags: php

how can I trim `<br>&nbsp;` from the end of a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Output = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote('<br>&'.'nbsp;').'$/i', '', $String);
```

Where `$String` is the input and `$Output` is the result.

Comment: Why the string concatenation inside preg_quote, if I may ask?

Comment: SO doesn't like the   entity (replaces with a real non-breaking-space ;)

Comment: er... why not replace it with &amp;nbsp; ?

Comment: Because strangely, SO doesn't replace &amp; with an ampersand :-/

Answer (score 1):

Slightly faster, if what you are trimming is constant:

```
$haystack = "blah blah blah <br>&"."nbsp;";
$needle = "<br>&"."nbsp;";
echo substr($haystack, 0, strrpos($haystack, $needle));
```

Comment: An interesting solution, but it will likely break if the needle also appears somewhere in the string, not necessarily at the end.

Comment: That is true. I've updated the solution to use strrpos instead of strpos, which searches from the end of the string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that works like PHPs `trim()` but with words

```
/**
 * Trim one or more words from a string
 * @param string   $string
 * @param string[] $words
 */
public function mb_word_trim( string $string, array $words ) : string
{
    // Cache the word lengths
    $wordLens = [];
    foreach ( $words as $word )
    {
        $wordLens[ $word ] = mb_strlen( $word );
    }

   $stringLength = mb_strlen( $string );

   // Loop until no words were trimmed
   do
   {
       $wordWasTrimmed = false;
       foreach ( $words as $word )
       {
            // Trim the start
            if ( mb_substr( $string, 0, $wordLens[$word] ) === $word )
            {
                $string = mb_substr( $string, $wordLens[$word] );
                $stringLength = mb_strlen( $string );
                $wordWasTrimmed = true;
            }

           // Time the end
           if ( mb_substr( $string, $stringLength - $wordLens[$word] ) === $word )
           {
               $string = mb_substr( $string, 0, $stringLength - $wordLens[$word] );
               $stringLength = mb_strlen( $string );
               $wordWasTrimmed = true;
           }

           // If a word was trimmed we need to restart the check from the begging of the array of words
           if ( $wordWasTrimmed )
           {
               break;
           }
       }
   } while ( $wordWasTrimmed );

   return $string;
}
```

Quick PHPUnit test

```
public function test_mb_word_trim() : void
{
    $string = "<br>  &nbsp; have some  BEER <br> don't mess with inner text  &nbsp; 123   &nbsp;";
    $wordsToTrim = [ '<br>', '&nbsp;', ' ', '' ]; // Note I've added an emoji to test multi byte

    $this->assertSame(
        "have some  BEER <br> don't mess with inner text  &nbsp; 123",
        \TGHelpers_String::mb_word_trim( $string, $wordsToTrim ),
    );
}
```